# MySQL allow remote connections from multiple ip addresses

Tags: mysql

I am aware of the command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

That will allow remote connections from the ip `1.2.3.4`, but what if I wanted to allow connections from both `1.2.3.4` and `5.6.7.8`?

Would it look like this?

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Or is this not allowed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run above command many times to GRANT access from multiple IPs.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'5.6.7.8' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

to all ips

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Would this mean that all remote machines would have to have the same password? I'm trying to set up a single MySQL server and have 2 machines also connect to it. The "easiest" way I could think of was to have the same password on the 2 remotes and use the command above. Is this safe? And production-recommended?

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL wildcards. 
instead of using limited numbers you can implement  a wildcard. this can be done by adding '%' instead of the numbers.